# Gmail API changes the content disposition from "inline" to "attachment"

Tags: gmail-api

I'm running into an odd problem with sending inline attachments via Gmail's API.  I am using the .NET client (version 1.10.0).  The email is a reply to a message I've received with an inline attachment, so the attachment is part of the quoted block in the reply.

Here's the raw MIME message that I'm sending out:

```
From: ...
To: ...
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 11:48:29 -0700
Subject: Re: attachment test #2
Message-Id: ...
In-Reply-To:...
References: ...
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=-JOa+9Bw0690XCFj1YCPc1Q=="

--=-JOa+9Bw0690XCFj1YCPc1Q==
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Id: <W4PKNTOPLYT4.32IVHE45EWK21@BILLRAVDIN9F02>

<div style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">back atcha.<div><br>On Fri, Jul 01, 2016 at 11:38 AM, ... wrote:<div>[Omitted for clarity]<img height="168" width="300" src="cid:8AF6D64A-9AAD-4E54-8998-5F08C42F537F"></span></div><br></div></div></div></div></div>
--=-JOa+9Bw0690XCFj1YCPc1Q==
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="ha ha.jpeg"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="ha ha.jpeg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Id: <8AF6D64A-9AAD-4E54-8998-5F08C42F537F>

[Base64 encoded attachment]

--=-JOa+9Bw0690XCFj1YCPc1Q==--
```

Note above the content disposition on the mime part for the inline attachment:

**Content-Disposition: *inline*; filename="ha ha.jpeg"**

Here's what the MIME headers on the inline attachment part look like when it comes in:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="ha ha.jpeg"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ha ha.jpeg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <8AF6D64A-9AAD-4E54-8998-5F08C42F537F>
X-Attachment-Id: 594301951148d672_0.1
```

My question is: why is the Content-Disposition now rewritten as **attachment** rather than **inline**?

I've found that when viewing the email in my browser, it appears as expected.  But when viewing with my Mac's Mail client, the inline attachment appears in the email twice.  I suspect that the change in the content disposition might be the reason- any light you can shed on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am running into the same problem. I tried using regular `smtplib` instead of the Gmail API to see if the messages don't get modified, but I couldn't manage to use it as Gmail blocks logging in with "less secure apps". This is really annoying.

Comment: 2018 and this is still happening. The weird thing is that the content-disposition is `attachment` on the sender side but `inline` on the receiver side.

Comment: I am having same issue when using iOS Gmail API ... did you find any solution